# Php code, add a condition to foreach loop

Tags: php, foreach

How can i make this code work? TY!

```
$site = '1'

    $mysites = array('1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6');
            foreach($mysites as $mysite) 
            {
            echo $mysites;  **but not the site with value 1**
            }
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A simple `if` will suffice:

```
$site = '1';

$mysites = array('1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6');
foreach($mysites as $mysite) 
{
    if ( $mysite !== '1' )
    {
        echo $mysite;
    }
}
```

or if you wan't to check against the `$site` variable:

```
$site = '1';

$mysites = array('1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6');
foreach($mysites as $mysite) 
{
    if ( $mysite !== $site )
    {
        echo $mysite;
    }
}
```

Comment: Anyway, `$site = '1'` isn't valid, `$site = '1';` is. Plus, `echo $mysites;` won't display anything since `$mysites` is an `array`. Please, don't copy/paste bad code from the OP question just to be faster to answer.

Comment: @ClemDesm I've fixed those errors. It wasn't my intention to answer as quickly as possible, I just completely missed those errors. Thanks for pointing them out!

Answer (score 6):

```
$site = '1'

    $mysites = array('1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6');

    foreach($mysites as $mysite) {
        if ($mysite == $site) { continue; }

        // ...your code here...
    }
```

Comment: well this is a very small and simple piece of code, which directly answers the question asked, and such a simple code is pretty much self explanatory... If not, would you advice me for the future what would be a suitable explanation for this one.

Comment: a small comment would be very helpful :) but who cares.. you are right. i apology.

Answer (score 3):

Just use an `if` statement:

```
foreach($mysites as $mysite) {
    if ($mysite !== $site) {
        echo $mysite;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do this:

```
$mysites = array('1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6');
        foreach($mysites as $mysite) 
        {
if($mysite != 1){
        echo $mysite;
}
        }
```

Comment: it was !==  this is was the problem and it fixed now

Comment: not the same result  you can watch this link
https://ibb.co/PxYBBsT